# Python: How do I reverse every other string in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to reverse every other words in a list. The list that I have is -

```
['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Fruits', 'Chocolate', 'Watermelon', 'Kiwi', 'Avacado', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Money']
```

How do I reverse every other word so the output should be.

```
['Bananas', 'selppA', 'Fruits', 'etalocohC', 'Watermelon', 'iwiK', 'Avacado', 'nomeL', 'Lime', 'yenoM']
```

The first letters don't have to be big I just had it like that.
Much appreciated

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  If so, we should only give hints rather than a solution.  The hints are 1) use ``[::-1]`` to reverse an individual string and 2) use ``range(start, stop, step)`` to loop over specific indicies.

Comment: I agree, OP hasn't posted anything that they tried either.

Comment: @PyWalker2797 I actually ended up trying a lot of things, I ended up wasting a lot of time trying to fix the <list_reverseiterator object at 0x03D66328> error I got, I just wanted some help and ofcourse learn from the answer. I really liked Raymond Hettinger answer I learned a lot fro m that

Answer (score 4):

Here's one simple way to do it:

```
>>> s = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Fruits', 'Chocolate', 'Watermelon', 'Kiwi', 'Avacado', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Money']
>>> for i in range(1, len(s), 2):
        s[i] = s[i][::-1]

>>> s
['Bananas', 'selppA', 'Fruits', 'etalocohC', 'Watermelon', 'iwiK', 'Avacado', 'nomeL', 'Lime', 'yenoM']
```

The `range(1, len(s), 2)` starts at position *1* and counts by twos.

The `[::-1]` reverses a string.

Answer (score 4):

I feel many of the solutions posted are quite clever, but may feel slightly too comprehendible for a beginner. This solution is not simple and uses a single step to achieve the result.

```py
>>> x = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Fruits', 'Chocolate', 'Watermelon', 'Kiwi', 'Avacado', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Money']
>>> [v[::1-(i%2)*2] for i, v in enumerate(x)]
['Bananas', 'selppA', 'Fruits', 'etalocohC', 'Watermelon', 'iwiK', 'Avacado', 'nomeL', 'Lime', 'yenoM']
```

Comment: I appreciate the humour in this.

Comment: Glad I could bring a smile @PyWalker2797 =)

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse a string `word` by writing `word[::-1]`, so the task is just to apply this for every other element. This can be solved with a list comprehension, using `enumerate` and checking whether the index is odd or even.

```py
>>> words = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Fruits', 'Chocolate', 'Watermelon',
             'Kiwi', 'Avacado', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Money']
>>> [ (word if i%2 == 0 else word[::-1]) for i, word in enumerate(words) ]
['Bananas', 'selppA', 'Fruits', 'etalocohC', 'Watermelon', 'iwiK',
 'Avacado', 'nomeL', 'Lime', 'yenoM']
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel many of the solutions posted are quite clever, but may feel slightly impenetrable to a beginner. This solution is quite simple and uses simple steps to achieve the result.

```
words = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Fruits', 'Chocolate', 'Watermelon', 'Kiwi', 'Avacado', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Money']

for index in range(0,len(words)):
    if index%2 != 0: #find every other 'index'
        words[index] = words[index][::-1] #reverse word at every other 'index'
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'word' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
list1 = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Fruits', 'Chocolate', 'Watermelon', 'Kiwi', 'Avacado', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Money']

[x[::-1] if i % 2 != 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(list1)]
['Bananas',
 'selppA',
 'Fruits',
 'etalocohC',
 'Watermelon',
 'iwiK',
 'Avacado',
 'nomeL',
 'Lime',
 'yenoM']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use map for iterating and enumerate to get the index. Check if the index is odd and then reverse using [::-1]

> Python 2

```
>>> v=['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Fruits', 'Chocolate', 'Watermelon', 'Kiwi', 'Avacado', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Money']
>>> map( lambda (i,x): x[::-1] if i % 2 == 1 else x , enumerate(v))
['Bananas', 'selppA', 'Fruits', 'etalocohC', 'Watermelon', 'iwiK', 'Avacado', 'nomeL', 'Lime', 'yenoM']
```

> Python 3

`list(map( lambda x: x[1][::-1] if x[0] % 2 == 1 else x[1] , enumerate(v)))`

The above will give a new list.
If you want same list to be modified, then

```
 >>> v=['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Fruits', 'Chocolate', 'Watermelon', 'Kiwi', 'Avacado', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Money']
 >>> for i,x in enumerate(v):
  ...  if i %2 == 1:
  ...    v[i]=v[i][::-1]
 >>> v
['Bananas', 'selppA', 'Fruits', 'etalocohC', 'Watermelon', 'iwiK', 'Avacado', 'nomeL', 'Lime', 'yenoM']
```

Comment: The question is tagged Python-3.x, so you should use `list(map(...))` for the result to be a list.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through your list by 2 like so

```py
for word in my_words[::2]:
    print(reversed(word))
```

This will step through your array but 2 and will print the word in reversed. You can also reverse a word by using `word[::-1]`

Comment: The problem is to reverse them in the list, not to print them. This also doesn't actually print the reversed words, because `reversed` doesn't return a string; it prints something like `<reversed object at 0x0000000003144898>`.

Comment: Sigh.. Fair enough. My bad.